# diameter of a graph with random edge weights

Tags: pr.probability, co.combinatorics

Given a weighted directed graph $G=(V,E, w)$, suppose we generate a new graph $G'=(V,E,w')$ with the same vertices and edges, but now letting the weight of edge $(i,j)$ be
an exponential random variable with mean $w_{ij}$. My question is: what is the
expected diameter of $G'$?

Why I'm interested in this: I was intrigued by the observation that the expected diameter of $G'$ can be
quite different from the diameter of $G$. Indeed, consider the following example: define $G$ by taking the complete graph $K_{n+1}$, picking an arbitrary vertex $a$, and assigning weight $n$  to any edge incident on $a$, and weight $1$ to 
every other edge. Then, the diameter of $G$ is $n$. On the other hand, the expected diameter
of $G'$ is O(1) since we can expect one of the edges incident on $a$ to have small weight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the special case of the complete graph $K_n$ which you mention in your post, Svante Janson answered your question in [this paper](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=971602); the answer is that the weighted diameter grows like $3 \log n$ in probability.

There is also some very nice [work by Bhamidi et. al](http://www.win.tue.nl/~rhofstad/ERRG_fin.pdf) on this question when the underlying graph is the giant component of Erdos--Renyi random graph $G_{n,c/n}$ with $c>1$ fixed, although they only prove lower bounds. [Amini et. al.](http://www.di.ens.fr/~amini/Publication/Flooding.pdf) (link is to a PDF) have found the asymptotics of the weighted diameter for random graphs with a given degree sequence, under some conditions, for degree sequences which in particular result in graphs which are with high probability connected. [Ding et.al.](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.1840) (Theorems 3.7 and 3.8 of the linked paper) prove quite refined estimates, and tail bounds, for the weighted diameter of random $d$-regular graphs, for $d \geq 3$. (Since random regular graphs are a special case of random graphs with a given degree sequence, the results of Amini et. al. and Ding et.al. have some overlap).

There is also related work, on the *hopcount* of randomly weighted graphs. The hopcount is what you get if you count the number of edges on the smallest-weight path. The primary interest of Bhamidi et. al. in fact seems to be hopcounts rather than weighted path lengths.

Answer (score 3):

The diameter is defined as $$d(G') = \sup_{x,y \in G} \inf_{\gamma} \sum_{e \in \gamma} w_{e},$$ where the infimum is over all paths $\gamma$ connecting $x$ to $y$, and the sum is over the edges $e$ which $\gamma$ crosses.  The graph structure is very crucial to this problem.  If the graph is very connected (as in your example), then the diameter is essentially the maximum value of the variables $\{w_i\}$.  A large fluctuation of a single $w_i$ will cause the diameter to be very large.

On the other hand, if you're dealing with something more like a lattice (e.g., a large, finite subset of $\mathbb Z^2$), then the diameter is a combination of many independent random variables.  Large fluctuations of any single variable will be muted and not affect the diameter much, and limit theorems will apply.  A variant of Kingman's subadditive ergodic theorem will show that $$d(G') \sim d(G).$$

Questions like this are very much in the realm of **first-passage percolation**.  Check out [this survey](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=i0BYqC-WVUsC&oi=fnd&pg=PA125&dq=models+of+first+passage+percolation+howard&ots=DJFDKBOO-B&sig=yG9r_xIOLf5zVeV0IiOlyMBOz8Y#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Howard, as well as [this one](http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.0649) by Blair-Stahn on the arXiv.

Comment: Thanks for the references; will check them out. In the very connected case, my intuition says that the opposite of your statement is true: even if one $w_{ij}$ is large, the existence of many paths between any two vertices will insure that the diameter is not strongly affected. 

Comment: Oops, you're absolutely right.  It should be the opposite of what I said:  the diameter should cluster on small values.  Say you want to connect x to y.  There's the one-edge path which connects them, and there are O(|G|) two-edge paths.  There is a very high chance that one of them will have a very small weight.  